# Permitir repetição de valor em JS

Tags: javascript

No trecho a seguir, verifica-se se o valor já existe dentro do vetor, caso não exista ele é inserido. Eu gostaria de poder fazer essa verificação normal, mas permitir que o '0' se repita. Ex:

```
 v_patr = [1,2,3,0,4,5,0]; //onde só o '0' pode ser inserido novamente.
 w_valor //é o valor recebido como parâmetro!

    if ((v_vet.indexOf(w_valor) == -1) && (w_valor != ""))
            {               
                v_vet[w_Cont_Qtde] = w_valor;
                w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde + 1;  
            }
```

Comment: E onde você usa o `v_patr`? Não dá só pra adicionar a condição `|| w_valor === 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você só precisa verificar se o número sendo inserido é igual a 0:

```
if ( (v_vet.indexOf(w_valor) == -1 && w_valor != "") || w_valor === 0) {               
   v_vet[w_Cont_Qtde] = w_valor;
   w_Cont_Qtde = w_Cont_Qtde + 1;  
}
```